# How to properly format a DEVPROP_TYPE_DATE?

Tags: c++, windows, wdk

I want to format a [DEVPROP_TYPE_DATE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/windows/hardware/ff543571(v=vs.85).aspx) value. The official documentation says:

"In Windows Vista and later versions of Windows, the DEVPROP_TYPE_DATE property type represents the base-data-type identifier that indicates that the data type is a DOUBLE-typed value that specifies the number of days since **December 31, 1899**. For example, **January 1, 1900, is 1.0**; January 2, 1900, is 2.0; and so on."

The [DEVPROPERTY structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn315030(v=vs.85).aspx) documentation says:

"DEVPROP_TYPE_DATE - date (DATE)"

So far, so good! But, wait! [DEVPROP_TYPE_DATE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/windows/hardware/ff543571(v=vs.85).aspx) format is similar, but it is not equal the [DATE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/82ab7w69(v=vs.140).aspx) datatype format:

"The DATE type is implemented using an 8-byte floating-point number. Days are represented by whole number increments starting with **30 December 1899**, midnight as time zero. Example: 30 December 1899, midnight is 0.00 and **1 January 1900, midnight is 2.00**."

And I found a [PDF document](http://hackipedia.org/Protocols/Microsoft%20Windows/UNSORTED/MS-PNPR%20Plug%20and%20Play%20Remote%20(PNPR)%20Protocol%20Specification%20(v20080207).pdf) saying that:

"DEVPROP_TYPE_DATE - Date value. PropertyBuffer specifies a 64-bit floating-point number representing the number of days (not seconds) since **December 31, 1899**. For example, **January 1, 1900, is 2.0**, January 2, 1900, is 3.0, and so on. PropertyBufferSize MUST be set to 8."

It seems to me as a lot of typos, but I'm not sure. I also found that the DATE datatype has a long history and some [weirdness](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/09/16/eric-s-complete-guide-to-vt-date.aspx). Someone can help me to clarify what is the correct format for a [DEVPROP_TYPE_DATE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/windows/hardware/ff543571(v=vs.85).aspx) value?

P.S.: I'm working on a B plan to display the value and compare it with the value shown by Device Manager. It's not perfect but close enough.

Comment: I *suspect* the discrepancy is because of a disagreement over whether the phrase "1 January 1900" means the moment at which 31 December becomes 1 January or the moment at which 1 January becomes 2 January.  Even "1 January 1900, midnight" seems ambiguous to me.  If I'm right, then the discrepancy itself resolves the ambiguity: the moment at beginning of 1 January 1900 is 1.0 and the moment at the end is 2.0.  **But I'm just guessing, so make sure you test this yourself if nobody can give you a definitive answer.**

Comment: I'm gonna to test and publish the result. Thank you @HarryJohnston !

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at the [DateTime.ToOADate()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tooadate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

Assuming data is an IntPtr pointing to the bytes of the date:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

var Bytes = new byte[8];
Marshal.Copy(data, Bytes, 0, 8);
var d = BitConverter.ToDouble(Bytes, 0);
var Value = DateTime.FromOADate(d).ToString();
```

Comment: Do you have any reference to support the assumption that the dates the device manager uses are in the same format as OLE automation dates?

Comment: No, I haven't found any. But the description of an OLE Automation date is remarkably similar to the device date.